# How can I batch convert files with simple PHP includes to HTML?

Tags: php, html, command-line, include

I have several old websites that use no php other than simple include lines like this:

```
<? include_once "includes/header.php"; ?>
```

Is there any way I can batch convert them over to HTML files so they contain the included content?

I'm hoping to host them as static files.

Comment: copy paste the content of that file where that line is

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I pieced together the following which finds all the php files and converts them to html:

`find . -iname "*.php" -print | while read filename; do php $filename > "${filename%.*}".html ; done`

**Breakdown:**

This finds all the php files in the current directory & child directories:

`find . -iname "*.php" -print`

This grabs the filename:

`| while read filename;`

This uses PHP to convert the files found to html:

`do php $filename > "${filename%.*}".html ; done`

Answer (score 1):

You could try opening the main PHP file in command line (instead of HTTP request) and outputing to a file.

```
php main.php > main.html
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have access to command line and PHP is installed on your machine you can use the following command the HTML files automatically (without copy/pasting).

```
$ php file.php > file.html
```